# Can I extend a generic file without a class?

Tags: python, import

I've got a generic python file, with a few basic functions. It does not have a `class` - just `def`s.

I've also got several specific files, which use the same functions from the generic one, and sometimes also extend/replace functions from it. Again, these do not have any classes. They just import the generic function.

When I import these files, I have to use them like this:

```
import genericFile as gf
import specificFile as sf

gf.doSomething()
gf.doSomethingElse() # BUG - This was replaced by a specific one.
# I should have used "sf.doSomethingElse()", but I'm a meatbag who makes mistakes
....
sf.doLastThing() # ERROR - This should be generic. There is no specific one.
```

Is there any way I can just import all of the functions from the first generic file into the specific file, and **only** import the specific one, to keep the code clean, readable, and error-free?

I know this would be quite easy to do with classes, but I'm asking for if there is support for this particular situation. It might be something similar to the `#include` macro in `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions everyone posted helped me come up with a slightly different answer. I tested it and found that if `specificFile` contained the import:

```
from genericFile import *
```

Then in any other file, I could import just the specific file, and it would properly chain the imports over to it:

```
import specificFile as sf

# All of these always get the most specific version.
sf.doSomething()
sf.doSomethingElse()
sf.doLastThing()
```

This means that the generic file is completely hidden, and the functionality of my project is not dependant on the order of my imports (which seemed risky).

---

**Note:** My linting tool is going absolutely crazy about this, so I'm not sure if it's intended/supported, let alone good practice?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. What does the tool complain about? The only catch is that this time your project is dependent on `sf ` importing `*` from `gf`. If someone changes the implementation of `sf` your code will fail.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as the functions in the second import will override the first ones:

```
from genericFile import *
from specificFile import *

doSomething()
doSomethingElse()
doLastThing()
```

Answer (score 1):

import just the functions you want, from the file you want
e.g.

```
from gebericFile import doSomething, doLastThing
from specificFile import doSomethingElse

doSomething()
doSomethigElse()
doLastThing()
```

That said maybe you need to consider better structure of your project/package

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a combination of `from x import *` and `from x import func_a, func_b`:

```py
from genericFile import *
from specificFile import doSomethingElse
```

If `genericFile` contains `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse`, the first line will make both of those available to you (you can use them as is like `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` without a prefix like `genericFile` or `gf`).

If `specificFile` contains `doSomethingElse`, then the second line will overwrite the `doSomethingElse` in your scope. Now if you call `doSomethingElse()` it will call the one from `specificFile`.